# What's your favorite bit-wise technique?

Tags: c, performance, bitwise-operators

A few days ago, StackExchange member Anto inquired about valid uses for [bit-wise operators.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65384/what-are-bit-operators-good-for/65463#65463) I stated that shifting was faster than multiplying and dividing integers by powers of two. StackExchange member Daemin countered by stating that right-shifting presented problems with negative numbers.

At that point, I had never really thought about using the shift operators with signed integers. I primarily used this technique in low-level software development; therefore, I always used unsigned integers. C performs logical shifts on unsigned integers. No attention is paid to the sign bit when performing a logical shift right.  Vacated bits are filled with zeros.  However, C performs an arithmetic shift operation when shifting a signed integer right.  Vacated bits are filled with the sign bit.  This difference causes a negative value to be rounded toward infinity instead of being truncated toward zero, which is a different behavior than signed integer division.

A few minutes of thought resulted in a first-order solution.  The solution conditionally converts negative values to positive values before shifting.  A value is conditionally converted back to its negative form after the shift operation has been performed.

```
int a = -5;
int n = 1;

int negative = q < 0; 

a = negative ? -a : a; 
a >>= n; 
a = negative ? -a : a;
```

The problem with this solution is that conditional assignment statements are usually translated to at least one jump instruction, and jump instructions can be expensive on processors that do not decode both instruction paths.  Having to re-prime an instruction pipeline twice makes a good dent in any performance gain obtained by shifting over dividing.

With the above said, I woke up on Saturday with the answer to the conditional assignment problem.  The rounding problem that we experience when performing an arithmetic shift operation only occurs when working with two's complement representation.  It does not occur with one's complement representation.  The solution to the problem involves converting a two's complement value to a one's complement value before performing the shift operation.  We then have to convert the one's complement value back to a two's complement value.  Surprisingly, we can perform this set of operations without conditionally converting negative values before performing the shift operation.

```
int a = -5;
int n = 1;

register int sign = (a >> INT_SIZE_MINUS_1) & 1

a = (a - sign) >> n + sign;
```

A two's complement negative value is converted to a one's complement negative value by subtracting one.  On the flip side, a one's complement negative value is converted to a two's complement negative value by adding one.  The code listed above works because the sign bit is used to convert from two's complement to one's complement and *vice versa*.  Only negative values will have their sign bits set; therefore, the variable ***sign*** will equal zero when ***a*** is positive.

With the above said, can you think of other bit-wise hacks like the one above that have made it into your bag of tricks?  What is your favorite bit-wise hack?  I am always looking for new performance-oriented bit-wise hacks.

Comment: This question & your account name - the world makes sense again...

Comment: +1 Interesting question as a follow up to mine and otherwise as well ;)

Comment: I also did some fast parity calculations once. Parity is a bit of a pain because traditionally it involves loops and counting if a bit is set, all of which requires lots of jumps. Parity can be calculated using shift and XOR, then a bunch of those done one after another avoids the loops and jumps.

Comment: Are you aware that there's a whole book about these techniques? - Hackers Delight http://www.amazon.com/Hackers-Delight-Henry-S-Warren/dp/0201914654

Comment: Yeah, there's a web site devoted to bit operations as well. I forget the URL but google will turn it up soon enough.

Comment: @nikie:  Yes, I am aware of *Hacker's Delight*. I am interested in unique real-world hacks that do not appear in a publication.

Comment: Few years too late, but there *is* indeed a valid solution for dividing by negative constants with a shift. Yours is broken for the maximum negative number (even assuming C guaranteed that over/underflow of signed numbers was defined). Hacker's delight btw does have the correct solution in it ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I love Gosper's hack (HAKMEM #175), a very cunning way of taking a number and getting the next number with the same number of bits set. It's useful, for example, in generating combinations of `k` items from `n` thusly:

```
int set = (1 << k) - 1;
int limit = (1 << n);
while (set < limit) {
    doStuff(set);

    // Gosper's hack:
    int c = set & -set;
    int r = set + c;
    set = (((r^set) >>> 2) / c) | r;
}
```

Comment: +1. But from now on, I'll have nightmares about finding this one during a debugging session *without* the comment.

Comment: @nikie, muahahahaha! (I tend to use this for things like Project Euler problems - my day job doesn't involve much combinatorics).

Answer (score 7):

The [Fast inverse square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) root method uses the most bizarre bit-level techniques to computing the inverse of a square root that I've ever seen:

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking [sic]
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what the fuck? [sic]
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
    //    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

    return y;
}
```

Comment: Fast sqrt is also amazing. Carmack looks to be one of the greatest coder.

Comment: Wikipedia has even older sources, e.g. http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/15/

Answer (score 0):

Division by 3 - without resorting to a run-time library call.

It turns out that division by 3 (thanks to a hint on Stack Overflow) can be approximated as:

X/3 = [ (x/4) + (x/12) ]

And X/12 is (x/4) / 3. There is an element of recursion suddenly appearing here.

It also turns out that if you limit the range of the numbers you are playing in, you can limit the number of iterations needed.

And thus, for unsigned integers < 2000, the following is a fast and simple /3 algorithm. (For bigger numbers, just add more steps). Compilers optimise the heck out of this so it ends up being fast and small:

```
static unsigned short FastDivide3(const unsigned short arg)
{
  unsigned short RunningSum;
  unsigned short FractionalTwelth;

  RunningSum = arg >> 2;

  FractionalTwelth = RunningSum >> 2;
  RunningSum += FractionalTwelth;

  FractionalTwelth >>= 2;
  RunningSum += FractionalTwelth;

  FractionalTwelth >>= 2;
  RunningSum += FractionalTwelth;

  FractionalTwelth >>= 2;
  RunningSum += FractionalTwelth;

  // More repeats of the above 2 lines for more precision

  return RunningSum;
}
```

Comment: Of course, this is only relevant on very obscure microcontrollers. Any real CPU made in the last two decades doesn't need a run-time library for integer division.

Comment: Oh sure, but small micros without a hardware multiplier are actually very common. And if you work in embedded land and want to save $0.10 on each of a million products sold then you better know some dirty tricks. That money saved = extra profit which makes your boss very happy.

Comment: Well, dirty... it's just multiplying by `.0101010101` (approx. 1/3). Pro tip: you can also multiply by `.000100010001` and `101` (which takes just 3 bitshifts, yet has the better approximation `.010101010101`

Comment: How might I do that with only integers and no floating point?

Comment: Bitwise, x*101 = x + x << 2. Similarly, x * 0.000100010001 is x >> 4 + x >> 8 + x >> 12.

Comment: @quickly_now: My comment is off-topic, but I found your "about me" to be a hoot.  I couldn't agree with you more about the Linux fan club.  The same eruption occurs if one dares to speak ill of open source software.

Comment: I've seen MS C++ output similar code for a division by a constant. Division is slow on some CPUs (even x86) compared to a multiplication and some bit operations. Essentially it multiplied by `2^32/c`, took the high 32 bits, and then applied some extra operations to handle the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in Erlang there is an entire DSL for doing bit operations. SO you can just break up a datastructure by bits by saying something like this:

<> = <<1,17,42:16>>.

Full details here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id75782