# In Java, why use bit hacks when non-bitwise technique it is more readable?

Tags: java, code-quality, performance, readability, bitwise-operators

Is there any legitimate use for [bit manipulation hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) in higher-level languages such as Java?

I can see them being useful in speed-sensitive low-level and computation-intensive programs, e.g. graphics processing or crypto functions. I guess that's why all collections of them are in C. However, getting to think about them in terms of higher-level design I cannot think of any point where I would, for example, write the following in a Java program:

```
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
```

rather than:

```
r = (x < y) ? x : y;
```

The first line looks more like an obfuscation than an improvement. And most applications have different kinds of bottlenecks - most commonly networks or disc access, so much so that any potential improvement gained by using a bitwise hack would be so tiny that it is completely ignorable.

This line of thought was provoked by a recent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473430/) in which someone was asked about a bitwise hack in Java during a interview.

I agree as much as anyone that it's always better to write faster code, but considering that it becomes much less readable, especially by someone not familiar with bit hacks, is there any kind of application in which it is legitimately worth it?

This question is not about bitwise *operators* in general, but more specifically about bitwise *hacks*, and even more specifically about bitwise hacks *in Java*.

By *bitwise hack* I mean a manipulation that has a trivial and/or obvious implementation, but which can be done slightly faster/better with some clever bitwise manipulation -- which in most cases makes it *near-unreadable* to someone not used to bitwise hacks.

---

There are similar looking questions: [Importance of bitwise thinking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136449/importance-of-bitwise-thinking) and [What are bit operators good for?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65384/what-are-bit-operators-good-for) The answers in these questions talk about bit manipulations in general, which yes, have a lot of clear and useful applications; especially in *other* languages like C. While this may seem similar, my question was about having them *versus* using the non-bitwise technique in Java. In the other questions this is not addressed at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are bit operators good for?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65384/what-are-bit-operators-good-for) and of [Importance of bitwise thinking](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/136449/importance-of-bitwise-thinking)

Comment: Regarding the provoking SO question: the best suggestion is to stay calm and don't be trolled (by your interviewer or a random question on SO). And as for legitimate use, you have already mentioned some: Java programmers who use colors and graphics (as simple as picking RGB colors) will do a small amount of bit manipulation. This would still apply if the heavy-lifting is done in another language. True "bit hacks" are employed by compilers as in [Peephole optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes, the specification of an algorithm is based on bit operations.  This is especially true in crypto work.

Crypto has another attribute to it that is important - that the operation takes exactly the same amount of time no matter what the parameters are.  This is to try to avoid leaking any data with timing attacks (there are even attacks based on the [sounds the computer makes while doing cryptography](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/12/new-attack-steals-e-mail-decryption-keys-by-capturing-computer-sounds/)).

Thus, for cryptography, it is of paramount importance that the code takes exactly the same amount of time and does the same things.  Bitwise operations can play a significant role in that area in that they are not often or easily optimized by the compiler.  With things were you can short circuit the expression or decide to follow one branch or another that has a different timing these are avenues of timing attacks.

The code

```
if(x < y) {
  r = x;
} else {
  r = y;
}
```

Can take different amounts of time based on the branch prediction and branching itself.  While

```
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
```

takes *exactly* the same amount of time each time through the code.  Branch prediction doesn't play a role because there are no branches in there.

---

With graphics work, there are similar areas of concern.  Some systems (especially older ones) had the CRT refresh tied with the clock cycle (for example [the Amiga](http://mandetech.com/2014/04/14/graphic-effects-on-the-amiga/) had 4 clock cycles per refresh line).  This meant that when you wrote code that was specifically tailored to the graphics of the system you knew *exactly* where the screen refresh was and could improve the appearance of the system.  This isn't quite as much of an issue now (the GForce GTX 780 can do 40,0000 operations per pixel per frame refresh), but it is something to be considered.

Secondly, there's also deep magic within fitting things into various caches on various systems.  Doing as much as possible with the cache can improve that.  This often means doing bitwise work rather than trying to load and store things or send them off to the [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit).

In Java, this can be difficult to know for certain, but again, maintaining a *consistent* frame rate based on the scene is something that is often very important with graphics.

Comment: The part about caches seems out of place. I've never seen a bit hack that uses less memory than the obvious way. If anything, they *add* lookup tables. Usually they only add bitwise operations, and sometimes (shorter) loops and branches. Occasionally a fast bit hack may make it worthwhile to calculate values on the fly instead of caching them but that too seems rather rare.

Comment: Side-channel countermeasure is more an art of machine code obfuscation than optimization.

Comment: @rwong when you are dealing with Java, you have difficulty getting the degree of machine code obfuscation that one would find in something closer to the metal. What you *do* have is the ability to avoid branches.  For crypto, its not about making it run fast (many times its intended to make it run slow), but to make it run *consistently*.

Comment: @MichaelT: agrees. So it is a bit amazing that while in C/C++ one could at least disable all compiler optimizations for one source file (containing the function), I couldn't even imagine how a Java execution environment (JIT or VM) could give you this kind of control.

Comment: @rwong by forcing the system to do things without branching and preforming all of the operations on each piece of data (even if they are null operations).  By using the bit version of min (the sample code), the system doesn't *know* what you are trying to do with those bit operations and so can't optimize out any of those operations.  As there are no branches, branch prediction isn't something that one can use to figure out the data. Thus, by careful choice of bit operations, one can avoid the compiler and runtime optimizations that could happen with branches and more straight forward code.

Comment: @MichaelT even though today's compilers might or might not be smart enough to unobfuscate (and optimize it *away*), future compilers (and those "AOT" compilers) might. Superoptimization is the vogue, but there is a lesser-known counterpart: [Superdiversification](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/77265/jacob08super.pdf), which lets the compiler generate the code with your criteria (e.g. no branches or discernible variations in power consumption). (Summary: hand over control to the tomorrow's compiler overlords.)

Comment: @rwong there's also aspects to that in reversible computing (and I've got another bit to add to my reading list).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15446/discussion-between-rwong-and-michaelt).

Comment: I'm not convinced that any code containing `<` is constant time. I've never seen it in crypto code claiming to be constant time. Typically alternatives like `(x-y)>>31` are used.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Its not the `<` that is the issue, its the `if` that is the issue.  That has a branch there and all sorts of things can happen under the covers (or even beyond if it gets compiled to native). It may not be possible to prevent all information leak based on how long things run, but that doesn't mean it *shouldn't* be done.

Comment: @MichaelT Removing the `if` is obviously necessary to avoid side-channels. But even without an if, I wouldn't trust `<` to be constant time. Since the output of a comparison goes to the flag register not to a normal register of x86, I wouldn't be surprised if a compiler emitted a branch to turn the flag into `0` or `1`. I've never seen `<` in code claiming to be constant time, always workarounds like subtract and shift.

Comment: @CodesInChaos ahh, ok, I see your point there (and the code I have is the code from the OP's question)...